# Windows safe mode vs normal mode

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 laptop that slows down to a crawl after about 30 minutes of use... I've tried the virus scan, malware scan, etc., but nothing found.  It works fine for hours in Safe Mode with Netowrking.  So I need a detailed list of what's disabled in Safe Mode, so I can try to pinpoint what it is that's causing problems... and any suggestions on how to narrow down the cause?

The only other solution is to do a full Windows re-install, which I'd rather not do. :)

Comment: Well, all the stuff started by Task Scheduler, for one.  An incredible amount of junk is added there by applications you install.  And on many systems the search scanner is a big performance hog.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @Ramhound You wrote "The detailed list is based on what is installed on YOUR laptop. Only you can provide us the list. " <--  He wasn't asking you to provide him for a list. He wants a detailed list, and a helpful answer would be telling him how he can get (from his computer) a detailed list.

Answer (score 0):

In safe mode only basic hardware drivers are loaded, only essential services are started. All customized start-up programs and scheduled tasks are disabled. It's very like to be one of the  auto start up programs you have. You could go into normal mode and open up task manager by press ctrl+alt+del to check what's using the a lot of CPU and memory. Press Window+r to open up the run window and run "msconfig" go to startup and it shows all the auto startup programs, you can untick them to disable them.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a cmd prompt and do `tasklist` and you get a list.

`tasklist >myfile`  would put that list in a file called myfile.

But I suggest another approach, is look at what was running in safe mode, then in normal mode open task manager and 'end task' everything not in safe mode. Or a load of things that aren't in safe mode.  And see if the problem still occurs and work it out by process of elimination.

There are so few things running in safe mode, you should get used to what is there in safe mode. You could just write them down, from the list you see in task manager.

Or you could do tasklist >myfile, from a command prompt, and then print out that file.